# How to take out spaces when reading a text file

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I am trying to write code that will transform a 160x160 table (where each column is a value of 5 digits and a dot, ex: "1.02456") into a single column. For example, the code would transform:

```
1 2 3 4 5  ->
1
2
3
4
5
```

However, the code I have currently prints the columns with the spaces included. Here is the current code:

```py
with open("zeaaa.txt", "rb") as file:
    byte = file.read(6)  
    byte.replace(" ", "")
    print(byte.decode)
 
    while byte:
        byte = file.read(6)  
        byte.replace(" ", "")
        print(byte.decode())
```

How can I modify this code to remove the spaces and print the single column as described above?

[Here is an example of the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDjOe.png)

Comment: Please make sure you share a [mre]

Comment: Hem, transform "1 2 3 4 5 -> 1 2 3 4 5" ???

Comment: "1.02456": you probably mean five *decimals*.

Comment: Is chatgpt using stackoverflow to create questions last days?

Comment: `byte = byte.replace(" ", "")`

Comment: @YvesDaoust That was a formatting issue that te author should have seen and fixed.

Comment: i dont see 5 digits in the image.  The problem is not clear. post the text and not the pictures of text.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

See [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=replace#bytearray.replace): `replace` **returns** a modified copy, it performs no in-place modification. Since you don't assign this result, it is lost.